# How to include a jquery datepicker plugin in a php code to input date of birth

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to include a jquery datepicker plugin downloaded from www.eyecon.ro ,for inputing date of birth.

I tried to follow the instructions as per in the documentation but i was not able to succeed in using the plugin.
currently am stuck at this phase of including datepicker in my php file.

i havent used jquery before but would like to use it with proper guidence.
Thank you

Comment: Please post your code with your problem.

Comment: datepicker is a javascript plugin. You need to call it from javascript, not php.

Comment: no the plugin i downloaded is a jQuery plugin,                       ifollowing is the link from which i had downloaded                                          http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/

Comment: Ok, i have downloaded the file from the link http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/ then i copied                                    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker.js"></script>    this to my php file as per instruction.  i would like to know what should be done next to input date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding input file is just the first step. The second step is to call js function in `document.ready()`. From the documentation, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#date').DatePicker({
      flat: true,
      date: '2008-07-31',
      current: '2008-07-31',
     calendars: 1,
     starts: 1
   });

});
```

You can change options as your need.

Comment: Should this be done inside my php code.   
can you please give me the right steps to be followed,
so that i could understand in a better way. am new to all this.

Comment: This should be placed after ` <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker.js">` in your php page.

Comment: i have done that.
i want to know what are the steps to be followed next inorder to input DOB using this plugin in the php code.

Comment: i have downloaded the file from the link eyecon.ro/datepicker then i copied 
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker.js"></script> 
to my php file as per instruction. i would like to know what should be done next to input date of birth to database through my php file using this datepicker jquery plugin..